# Entire solutions of polynomial ODE's

Tags: ca.classical-analysis-and-odes

Consider a differential equation of the form
$$f^{(n)}(z)=P(z,f(z),f'(z),...,f^{(n-1)}(z))$$
where $P$ is a polynomial in $n+1$ variables, with the initial condition (for definitness)
$$f^{(k)}(0)=0,\qquad 0\leq k\leq n-1.$$
By the ODE existence theorem, there exists a unique solution $f(z)$ which is holomorphic 
near the origin of the complex plane. My question is whether it is possible to decide
whether $f(z)$ can be analytically continued to the whole complex plane. For example, suppose
that the coefficients of P are rational numbers. Is there a finite decision procedure that 
will take P and determine whether $f(z)$ is entire?

Comment: Don't you need to specify some derivatives of f at zero to get uniqueness?

Comment: @Leonid. Sure: $f''=f+(f')^5-f^4$ with the solution $f(z)=0$. This example is rather stupid, of course, but how exactly do you suggest to rule such things out? 

Comment: OK, how about $f''=f+(f')^5-f^5$ with $f(z)=e^z$ then (subtract $1+z^2$ yourself to make it an unrecognizable mess)

Comment: Scott: Thankyou for the correction. I should have written
$f^{(k)}(0)=0,\;\;1\leq k\leq n-1$

Comment: 
Leonid's question and fedja's response brings to mind the question 
whether any entire solution of such a differential equation is
also a solution of linear equation. I don't know the answer. Even if
it is positive, it will lead to the solution of the decision problem
only if it can be decided whether the solution of such a 
nonlinear equation is also the solution of a linear one.



Comment: It's also possible to formulate a somewhat more general question for which the linear equation issue will (probably) not be relevant, by allowing $P$ to be a rational function, in which case there
are probably many examples of entire functions which are not solutions
of linear equations. E.g. $f(z)=e^{e^z}$ solves $f''(z)=\frac{(f'(z))^2}{f(z)} +f'(z)$, but I would guess it doesn't
solve any linear differential equation with coefficients that are 
polynomials in $z$ (proof?). 


Comment: As a side note, the old question of Borel whether the existence of a polynomial differential equation implies any restriction on the growth rate of an entire function is still wide open. If every function solving a polynomial equation solved a linear one, the answer would be trivially yes, so there is little hope to prove that. But I don't know if there are explicit counterexamples.

Comment: Could it be that the Borel problem you mentioned relates to the 
more general equation $P(z,f(z),f'(z),...f^{(n)}(z))=0$, and has
a known solution in the case that the equation is of the form 
$f^{(n)}(z)=P(z,f(z),f'(z),...f^{(n-1)}(z))$? Just wondering..

(of course my original question can also be formulated for the more
general form of the differential equation).

Comment: @GK: I wonder about the reasons of your question, since in such general settings the problem looks really untreatable. If it is not a question for a question, so you have an example in mind, please be more specific. There could be some knowledge in the case $n=1$ which is very special. Otherwise, an example for $f(z)=e^z-z-1$, namely $y''=y^2-{y'}^2+(2z+1)y'-z^2+1$, shows that any perturbation of the coefficients results in the non-entire solution.

Comment: @Wadim: My question was not prompted by a specific example. Rather,
I was thinking about the fact that writing a polynomial ODE with initial conditions is an explicit way to define a holomorphic function, so that it is natural to wonder what properties of the function can be deduced from this representation. It seems that indeed
 it is harder than I suspected.

Can you give a hint as to how you show that any perturbation of the
example you gave leads to a non-entire solution?

Comment: Formal proofs are really hard in such cases! My "proof" is completely experimental in nature (plus some personal experience with algebraic ODEs). The case of linear ODEs in your settings is easy because their coefficients lie in $\mathbb C[z]$, hence no singular points for their solutions (except at infinity). In the nonlinear case no control of the singularities is available: they "move" as singularities of the correpsonding DE. I know the existence of general theorems of global behaviour of solutions if $n=1$ but nothing general for $n>1$.

Comment: @Wadim: I understand the general intuition is that in any case where you have an entire solution, an arbitrarily small perturbation will destroy this. This can be stated as the following conjecture: consider the space of polynomials $P$ in $n+2$ variables with degree  $d\geq 2$. Give it the natural topology. Then the set of $P$'s for which an entire solution exists is nowhere dense (doesn't contain any open set).

Comment: @GuyKatriel  Could  you please give a reference for this  conjecture?thanks

Answer (score 1):

One way to see that the local holomorphic function $f$ is entire is to see if the ODE defined by the polynomial $P$ is integrable. If its not, then you can assure that the solutions are not entire due to the fact that a non-integrable ODE has solutions with singularities. In fact, this is the way to show non-integrability for ODE, to find the singularities of some certain solutions.

For an explicit example, you can search on the vast literature about the integrability question of the Henon-Heiles system.

Hope this is what you were searching.

Comment: Is the criterion you are talking about really an if-and-only-if one?
Does the lack of singularities imply integrability in the sense 
you refer to?

Comment: It's a perfect strategy to decide whether a given algebraic differential equation is integrable. But as far as I know there are no general algorithms (except maybe the 1st order DEs).

Comment: Thank you kaminoite and Wadim for the very interesting connection with the question of integrability. 
A quick search led me to a review paper by Martin D.Kruskal, Nalini Joshi, Rod Halburd http://arxiv.org/abs/solv-int/9710023
There, the authors state that
"There is strong evidence [60, 61] that the integrability of a nonlinear sytem is intimately related to the singularity structure admitted by the system in its solutions."
It seems from this formulation that the relation 
is not entirely established. 
If you can recommend other sources that clarify this, I would be most grateful.

Comment: The integrability would (normally) lead to the complete description of singularities of the solutions. But there are many classical non-integrable examples where this task can be done as well. The simplest one is probably the Chazy equation $y'''=2yy''-3y'^2$ and then we have Painleve transcendents,--in these cases the equations possess many symmetries. The moral is that the integrability is helpful when it happens (0% probability for a random polynomial ODE); if it does not happen there is still a chance to have entire solutions. This is not an answer, because I can hardly figure out refs.